# shell_exec nmap php not working with different version

Tags: php, shell-exec, nmap

I have a very strange problem.
I'm trying to make a program that executes `shell_exec()` in PHP with NMAP.

The problem comes when I put `shell_exec("nmap --version")`, because it returns me `version 4.11`, but when I put it directly on shell, it returns me `version 7.01`.

Answer (score 0):

When using shell_exec you should always use the full path to the executable.